# Change the error message for validation

Tags: javascript

I am using following [link](http://inchoo.net/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/) for displaying validation error messages.

as I am using this : **validate-length** I am getting error message as :

`Text length does not satisfy specified text range` , but I want to change this message as:

"`Zip code is not servicable`"

```
<input placeholder="Enter your PIN Code" class="input-text 
   <?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('postcode')):?>
      required-entry
   <?php endif;?> 

   validate-length maximum-length-6 minimum-length-6 validate-digits"
   type="text"
   id="estimate_postcode"
   name="estimate[postcode]" 
   value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFieldValue('postcode')) ?>" 
   onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false;}"
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `validate-length` which uses that as the error message. These classes are defined in js/prototype/validation.js. You could use the class `valid-zip` which would check the zipcode, but the error message would be different. You probably should just make your own. It shouldn't be hard be using the other validations in the file to figure out how.

Comment: Did you have any luck?

Comment: Hi , I am working on  this, i will let you know soon.

Comment: Good to hear. Let me know if you have additional issues.

Comment: I'll take a look as soon as we sort this one out. Are we good here?

Comment: Ok, if this is what you needed then I guess accept it as the correct answer and lets move to your next issue.

Comment: this is awesome, thanks a lot, its worked like a charm, never expected it will solve this much  easily. full credits for you.

Comment: can you please look at other issue & help me...